# Filtering undefined files in PFQuery

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pffile

I'm using Parse as a backend for storing image-based news items. Each news item has an image file. Some image files are 'undefined' and some have jpegs. I have an iOS app front end which shows news items in a PFQueryTableViewController. In the QueryForTable, I'd like to filter out records with undefined files.

I've tried this with no joy:

```
    - (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
        [query orderByDescending:@"EntryTime"];
        [query whereKey:@"Image" notEqualTo:@"undefined"];
        return query;
    }
```

And also:

```
    [query whereKey:@"Image" notEqualTo:@"null"];
```

Anyone know what the right way to treat 'undefined' files is?

Thanks!

Comment: whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"Image"

Comment: @danh Thanks! Very useful. This worked - [query whereKeyExists:@"Image"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
    [query whereKeyExists:@"Image"];
```

in

```
    - (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
            [query orderByDescending:@"EntryTime"];
            [query whereKeyExists:@"Image"];
            return query;
        }
```